# Fewer publications hinder postdoc opportunities?

Tags: publications, postdocs, job-search, stem

I graduated with PhD in a STEM field from a good university in the US with only one "good" journal paper published currently. I am working on another one but it won't appear in my CV since I am sending out applications for postdoc jobs starting this month. I would like to have a reality check on whether I stand anywhere near to getting a postdoc position? or it will only be a futile activity on my part. I am considering applying in both US and EU. Your insights much appreciated.

Comment: As someone who hires post-docs, it is not unusual to see only a small number of published papers and a number in progress. List both on your CV, update as needed, and be prepared to talk about all of them. Papers are just one indicator, what people have worked on and might be willing to work on is at least as important (to me).

Comment: Even in STEM, the variations between fields are huge. In my field it might be hard to get a (good) postdoc with just one good publication, but in others it might be more likely.

Comment: Mine is Mechanical engineering, in particular.

Comment: Ultimately, there's only one way to find out.  You can only apply with the research record you have.

Comment: I would say apply even if you are not a strong candidate, unless it's a complete waste of time. The bursary that made the difference during my PhD was given to me because someone dropped out.

Answer (score 2):

In my field (computer science with AI/ML), I would say that in most cases, having no publications after graduation is a very bad sign - most researchers would not allow a student to graduate without at least one good publication, let alone hire a postdoc with no publications.

However, I think that the answer strongly depends on your specific field. What is the accepted number of publications that young researchers in your field have? The variance is massive - it's not unusual for AI/ML PhD students to have upwards of 5 publications at top venues upon graduation; in some fields one can have only preprints and zero peer-reviewed published works.

If your publication record is way lower than your peers', then you could still get a reasonable postdoc, assuming that you have additional proof of your greatness. This can be in the form of really promising work in progress, reference letters from prominent people in your community (not just your advisor, whose strong support is a given), achievements in teaching/community service etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, publications should not affect if you have sufficient experience and skills in the research project you are applying to and research field of the group you wish to join. Hiring postdoc researchers usually involves discussions with the professor who is hiring the postdoc researcher and probably a hiring committee at the institution. Therefore I think you may have the chance to describe your research activities and skills. You can also talk about your papers which are under preparation and those submitted and under review.

Therefore, as far as you can discuss your background and experience with your future mentor, I do not see any reason to be worried about part of your research publication which still need time to be published. People being responsible in hiring you, will see a package of your skills, experience, quality of your studies and many other factors and these can help increase your chances of finding a good postdoc position.

Comment: You can, of course, have a listing for "work in progress" on your CV. The work needn't be invisible.

Comment: @Buffy of course. I have seen many CVs listing their work in progress, work to be submitted, etc. Listings to show they are much involved in research and publication.

Comment: The reason why I, as a hiring PI, value publications rather highly is that it indicates the skill of "being able to complete projects". I care about results, and about hiring team members that can produce them.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper A publication may not be a "result". For instance you can often easily publish the thing multiple times. "When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure." (Goodhardt)

Comment: @anderstood Of course, I will also look at the papers. If there are many re-publications of the same work, that would be a red flag for me. But a lack of papers is a red flag as well.